# How to add Actionlisteners to a Video application

Tags: java, swing, video, vlcj

I have created a java swing application where i am running a video in canvas using VLCJ. Everything does fine but now i need add play/pause buttons and also sliders. So my question is how to add an actionlistener which would pause my video. Here is my code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;


import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import com.sun.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Player implements ActionListener{

   JButton b1;
   Player vid = null;
   JButton  playbutton, pausebutton;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Player(args);
            }
        });
    }

    private Player(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj Tutorial");


        MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBackground(Color.black);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
       c.setBounds(100, 500, 1050, 500);
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.setBounds(100, 50, 1050, 600);
        frame.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel ();

        p1.setBounds(100, 900, 105, 200);
        frame.add(p1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        playbutton =new JButton();

        playbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("pics/playbutton.png"));
        playbutton.setBounds(50, 50, 150, 100);
        playbutton.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
        p1.add(playbutton); 

        pausebutton=new JButton();

        pausebutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("pics/pausebutton.png"));
        pausebutton.setBounds(80, 50, 150, 100);

        p1.add(pausebutton); 



        EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

       // c.addComponentListener((ComponentListener) mediaPlayer);
       mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));

        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.setSize(1050, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        mediaPlayer.playMedia("D:\\Facebook.mp4");
        //NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your Action Performed:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

     Object obj = ae.getSource();
     if(obj == btnPlayButton){
         //Play Your Video
       }
      if(obj == btnPauseVideo){
          //PAuse your Video
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `mediaPlayer` reference declared as a class field rather than an automatic heap variable as you have now.

The main reason for doing that is to make sure it is not garbage collected - otherwise it becomes eligible for garbage collection when your constructor method exits. This is necessary because that media player component is wrapping a native media player component, and if your Java object instance disappears the native media player will crash some time later - when it tries to call back into your Java object, it's not there.

The same applies to your `mediaPlayerFactory` reference.

Moving the `mediaPlayer` variable to a class field also makes it possible to easily implement your action listener:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object obj = e.getSource();
    if (obj == btnPlayButton) {
        mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().play();
    }
    else if (obj == btnPauseVideo) {
        mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().pause();
    }
}
```

There are many ways to implement those listeners, e.g. you could have one listener per button rather than sharing the listener like this.

There are *lots* of examples in the vlcj test sources that show precisely how to do this.

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/tree/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test

Comment: That's great, maybe you should accept the answer to close this question?